# Get Selected Item Of ListBox using ContextMenu

Tags: wpf, listbox, contextmenu

I am working on WPF. I have ListBox and I am adding ListBox Items programatically through "ObservableCollection" as I have to add and remove at runtime. I am having ContextMenu on ListBoxItems. Now I want to get the selected item by clicking on the contextmenu. Here is my code:

.cs

```
    ObservableCollection<string> MyItems = null;

    public MessageTrcr()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MyItems = new ObservableCollection<string>();

        listofConnectedItems.ItemsSource = MyItems;

        CreateListItem("Sandeep");
        CreateListItem("Gopi");
    }

    public void CreateListItem(String ItemName)
    {
        MyItems.Add(ItemName);
    }
    private void MenuItemStart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // What should I write here to get selected Item
    }
```

and .xaml

```
<Grid>
    <ListBox x:Name="listofConnectedItems" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}"  >
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10">
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListBox.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu x:Name="contextMenu">
                <MenuItem Header="_Start" Click="MenuItemStart_Click" />
                <MenuItem Header="Sto_p"  />
                <MenuItem Header="_Clear" />
            </ContextMenu>
        </ListBox.ContextMenu>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Here is the screenshot.

[image]

When I right click on Gopi and click on Start I want "Gopi" in `MenuItemStart_Click`

Now what should I write in "MenuItemStart_Click" event to get the selected Item. I tried `e.OriginalSource as MenuItem` and `sender as MenuItem` but of no use. Can any one please get me through this. Thanks in advance

Comment: listofConnectedItems.SelectedItem ? that should give it to you

Comment: @adminSoftDK Thanks dude. It worked perfectly. I am not getting how I missed it. Anyway thank u :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not bind the selected item property also?

```
 <ListBox 
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItemProperty, Mode=TwoWay}"
    x:Name="listofConnectedItems" 
    Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}"  >
```

Then in your code next to your observable collection

```
public string SelectedItemProperty {get; set;}
```

Comment: I checked your code, but its showing nothing. As @adminSoftDK said "listofConnectedItems.SelectedItem" is working. Anyway Thanks :)

Comment: @Gopi I assure you that this is the proper way to do it. Accessing objects via name in the behind code isn't maintainable. What happens when you switch to an MVVM structure? lol Anyhow, good luck with that.